# how to access linux shell on Chromium

Tags: chromium

I have a Google chrome computer, which I'd like to install Dropbox on.  Dropbox provides instructions for installing on Linux here https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx, however, I need to figure out how to enter Linux commands on Chromium. This webpage http://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/poking-around-your-chrome-os-device suggests two ways to do it. First, you can get a command prompt through VT-2 by doing this, with the arrow being the right arrow key above the three on the keyboard.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>

When I try this, I get no response (even when I'm in developer mode).

The other way to get the command prompt is through crosh, like this

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

This opens the crosh shell for me, but none of the commands for installing dropbox work for me. For example, I get the error  'cd'` is not a command when I try to run the first line (shown below) for installing dropbox. It also doesn't accept 'shell' command or 'sudo'

For installing dropbox on linux.

```
32-bit:

cd ~ && wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86" | tar xzf -
64-bit:

cd ~ && wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86_64" | tar xzf -
Next, run the Dropbox daemon from the newly created .dropbox-dist folder.

~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
```

Answer (score 0):

The `crosh` shell is the only level of Linux shell that you can get with a ChromeBook without enabling `Developer Mode` which means you must heed this warning: `Caution: Modifications you make to the system are not supported by Google, may cause hardware, software or security issues and may void warranty`.

Comment: Thanks, can you tell me why I can't run the shell commands in my OP?

Comment: I did enable developer mode and still can't access the Linux shell other than through the crosh shell.